# Arabic text not displaying properly in textarea component in ios devices (Adobe AIR)?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, textarea, flash-cs6

I am making an application in Flash CS6, Adobe air 18 and actionscript 3. I'm using a textarea component for chat functionality but it is not displaying Arabic text properly. Letters are being incorrectly separated.

How can I solve this?

This problem is only occurring for mobile devices. For desktop everything looks fine.

[image: Application screenshot]

Comment: show us what you have tried and perhaps put some screenshots for us to help you better.

Comment: how to add screenshots here@Gurtej Singh

Comment: When editing, use CTRL+G or click the image icon in your toolbar.

Comment: One more thing it is working for desktop.but not working in mobile devices ios devices.@Gurtej Singh

Comment: added screenshot@Gurtej Singh.it is displaying like that.but actual is لاىراىلاابيلاياتايسلغففقغعهعخلاىاىلالاىربشسصغلا م like this.

Comment: Have you embedded your fonts properly? I seriously cannot make out any difference between your screenshot and the actual text you pasted, not because its not clear, I don't understand the language!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87232/discussion-between-usha-kommuri-and-gurtej-singh).